# Delete selected short paths from a graph in igraph

Tags: r, igraph, vertices, subgraph

Dear Community Members:

I wanted to ask if there is a way to choose what nodes to graph on igraph. I am running the following code:

```
library(igraph)
    g <- graph.adjacency(
  as.matrix(as.dist(cor(t(POS_testing), method="pearson"))),
  mode="undirected",
  weighted=TRUE,
  diag=FALSE
)
g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple=TRUE, remove.loops=TRUE)
g <- delete_edges(g, E(g)[which(E(g)$weight<0.9)])
```

Looking at my Vertices:

```
V(g)$comp <- components(g)$membership
V(g)$comp
[1]  1  2  3  4  3  5  6  7  3  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  3  3  3 17 18 19 20 15  3 21  3
[30]  3  3  3 22 23  3  3  3  3 24 25  3 26 27 28  3 29  3  3  3 30 31  3  3  3  3  3  3 32
[59]  3 33  3  3 34 35  3  3 28 28 36 37 38  3 39 28  3  3  3  3 40 21 21  3 41  3  3 42  3
[88]  3  3  3  3  3 43 44  3 45  3 46  3 47 48  3  3  3  3  3  3 49  3  3  3  3 50  3  3  3
[117]  3 51  3  3 52 53 52 52 54 55 52  3 56 57 58 55 59  3 60 61  3 62  3 63 64 65 66 67  3
[146]  3  3  3 68  3 69 64 70 71  3 72  3 73 74  3  3 75  3  3  3  3 32 76  3 77  3 78  3  3
[175] 79 80  3 81 82  3  3 73  3  3  3 83 84 85 73  3  3  3  3  3 86 32 87
```

Now, running this command that I found here: [Delete unconnected short paths from a graph in igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133971/delete-unconnected-short-paths-from-a-graph-in-igraph) I can get  Vertices that are assigned to the number '3'.

```
g <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)$comp == 3)
V(g)$comp
[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[45] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[89] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

However, I would like to choose more than just the vertices assigned to 3. I would like to choose to display 3, 21, 28, 32, 52, and 73.

I ran into this website: http://igraph.org/r/doc/delete_vertices.html
So, I ran the code:

```
t <- delete_vertices(g, comps$Var1)
```

Where comps$Var1 is a numeric vector of all the numbers (displayed above) that I want removed (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 5, etc.). It did not work. I still have all 197 numbers popping up when I run `V(t)$comp`.

Next I tried to manually fill it in instead & ran the following code (3 occurs 96 times, 21 occurs 3 times, etc):

```
V(g)$comp <- c(rep(3, 96), rep(21, 3), rep(28, 4), rep(32, 3), rep(52, 4), rep(73, 3)).
```

This did not work either.

Next I tried to add_edges instead (just these to see if it would work):

```
t <- add_edges(g, c(which(V(g)$comp == 3), which(V(g)$comp == 21), which(V(g)$comp == 28)))
```

This still produced all numbers above and did not selectively choose these numbers for me to graph.

I've also tried using the & operator like this:

```
g <- induced_subgraph(g, c(V(g)$comp == 3 & V(g)$comp == 21 & V(g)$comp ==29))
```

This also kept all my vertices.

I am out of ideas and I am asking this community if this is even possible. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `POS_testing` to reproduce your example but try out:

`g <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)$comp %in% c(3, 21, 28, 32, 52, 73))`

Comment: ANG - you are a true genius. Thank you very much! Yes!! This solved it. I can't click on 'Up' bc of my low reputation, but please know I sincerely appreciate this! :-)

Comment: You're welcome @Purrsia ! Don't worry about Upvote, you can just accept the answer for the SO community :-)